# Neo4j delete with skip and ordering

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to delete all nodes with the `User` label which have a property `deactivated` set on it, except for the most recently created 20 nodes.

Retrieving them is easy:

```
MATCH (x:User {deactivated: true}) RETURN x ORDER BY x.created_at DESC SKIP 20
```

What would be the equivalent deletion statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `RETURN` statement with a `WITH` and pass the results to `DETACH DELETE`.

```
MATCH (x:User {deactivated: true}) 
WITH x 
ORDER BY x.created_at DESC 
SKIP 20
DETACH DELETE x
```